# Facing issue while installing Cassandra on MacOs

Tags: java, macos, cassandra, jmx, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to install Cassandra 3.11 on MacOs (M1) . I am using tarball installation and following the official installation guide. But when I try to run Cassandra using
`bin/cassandra` , I am facing the following error.

```
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
```

I have installed openjdk version "1.8.0_292" . Can anyone guide me what I am missing out and help me resolve this bug.

Error

```
INFO  18:22:13 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  18:22:14 Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 499MB
INFO  18:22:14 Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 499MB
ERROR 18:22:14 Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:390) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:252) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(RMIServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:37) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.24.jar:3.0.24]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:254) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:213) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:144) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon$JmxRegistry.<init>(CassandraDaemon.java:869) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.24.jar:3.0.24]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:148) [apache-cassandra-3.0.24.jar:3.0.24]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:197) [apache-cassandra-3.0.24.jar:3.0.24]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:611) [apache-cassandra-3.0.24.jar:3.0.24]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:804) [apache-cassandra-3.0.24.jar:3.0.24]
```

Comment: is it really error? looks like the compiler messages

Comment: I agree with Alex here.  That's not an error.  Are you sure Cassandra's not running?  Remember, just running `bin/cassandra` runs it in the _foreground_, so the next action on that terminal kills the process.

Comment: I have edited the description of my question and added the exact errors. Hope that helps . Also when I try to access cqlsh , i get error                          
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ERROR 18:22:14 Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is: 
  java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

Ok, so something else on your Mac is using the JMX port (7199).  Find whatever that is and stop it, or set `JMX_PORT` in `cassandra-env.sh` to a free port.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for helping me resolve this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing Cassandra with brew

```
brew update

brew install cassandra
```

Comment: I tried installing with brew , but got error.  ```Error: cassandra: no bottle available!```